# How can I show that $n=k+(k+1)+\cdots+(k+m)$

Tags: number-theory, natural-numbers

How can i show that every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as summing up to $n$ togheter with some succeeding consecutive numbers?

In other way:

> $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists k,m \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } n=k+(k+1)+\cdots+(k+m)$$

Thanks

Comment: Try $k=n$ and $m=0$.

Comment: If you don't like $1$-term sums, you'll have a problem for $n=2$ and for $n=4$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen! So you think $m=0$ is a natural number! :)

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi: Of course it is. But if you want to exclude it, see my other comment.

Comment: @Nilan: Your term $+1$ is not in the right place.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I have checked wiki and it was written there that "There is no universal agreement about whether to include zero in the set of natural numbers...". It is very funny! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true for $n=2^\alpha$. Since if 
$$
n = k+(k+1)+...+(k+m),
$$
then
$$
2^{\alpha+1} = 2k(m+1)+m(m+1)=(2k+m)(m+1).
$$
As $(2k+m)+(m+1) = 2k+2m+1$ is an odd number, one of them must be one which is not possible since $2k+m>1$ and $m+1 >1$.

If $n$ be an odd number, it is very straightforward. So let $n=2^\alpha\beta$, where $\beta>1$ is an odd number.
If $2^\alpha>\beta$, then 
 set $m=\beta-1$ and $k=2^\alpha+\frac{1}{2}(\beta-1)$. If $2^\alpha<\beta$, set $m=2^\alpha-1$ and $k = \frac{1}{2}(\beta-2^\alpha+1)$.

Thus, the claim is true for all natural numbers which are not a power of $2$.